# Open windows explorer from a web-based (PHP) application

Tags: php, windows, explorer

I am developing a Web Application for the company I work for using PHP/MySql/Javascript.  This application needs to be able to open windows explorer to view files stored on the network (I:) drive.

Everything I have found suggests that this is not possible from a browser application - it MUST be possible.  I've played around with exec(), , header(Location: I:)...which all seemed like they would be simple solutions --- negatory ghostrider.

Help !

Comment: do you mean like the `choose file` button [on this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gEGse/2/) ? Why would you need to open explorer other than to browse for a file to upload ?

Comment: The only way you're going to get that to work is if your webapp server is able to also mount the network drive.

Comment: `it MUST be possible` - no, it should not. Imagine opening website that every 0.5 sec opens new explorer window. Unfortunately it is possible with Internet Explorer and ActiveX.

Comment: You can design add-on and ask the company to install it on their computer or use ActiveX! I don't think there is any pretty solution here!

Comment: @LyubenTodorov - Yes!  Thanks man. Don't even need the buttons - just need to open up to a specific directory to view some pictures/info files -- a little bit of horseplay with this code here should solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer 6 lets you do this via `window.open('file:///K:/');` (sorry that's the best I can do from my Linux box.)

Comment: Thanks Neil - need more cross-browser compatibility though.  The latest versions of all browsers prevent this type of action.

Answer (score -1):

Because of a security feature. It will not work on all browsers. If you are desperate enough, you could knock together a java apple or flash to do it. But you might need to physically set the security descriptor on the browser.